# npm install suddenly fails with various errors, including permission denied (with & without sudo) on Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, npm, permissions, node-modules, sudo

Today when I was trying to install all packages with npm i, I get the permission denied, with and without giving the commands as sudo. Using sudo also produces additional errors. I think I messed something up with permissions last night when I was tweaking and experimenting the app; it worked fine before. I tried changing permissions as per solutions posted from previous, similar questions but those didn't work.

Installing specified packages works; the command break only when I try to install all the packages. I used --allow-root and --unsafe-perm=true as a hack to get the command to work, but I would like to have a more safe and systematic solution. Here are the errors:

Without sudo:

```
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /home/user/project/node_modules
npm WARN tsutils@3.17.1 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! path /home/user/project/node_modules
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/home/user/project/node_modules'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/home/user/project/node_modules'] {
npm ERR!   stack: "Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/home/user/project/node_modules'",
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/home/user/project/node_modules'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/user/.npm/_logs/2019-12-03T04_30_10_304Z-debug.log
```

With sudo:

```
> node@8.10.0 preinstall /home/user/project/node_modules/node
> node installArchSpecificPackage

npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /home/user/project/node_modules/node
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! path /home/user/project/node_modules/node
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/home/user/project/node_modules/node'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/home/user/project/node_modules/node'] {
npm ERR!   stack: "Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/home/user/project/node_modules/node'",
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/home/user/project/node_modules/node'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/user/.npm/_logs/2019-12-03T04_30_23_864Z-debug.log
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:895
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'node-linux-x64/package.json'
Require stack:
- /home/user/project/node_modules/node/installArchSpecificPackage.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:892:15)
    at Function.resolve (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:80:19)
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/user/project/node_modules/node-bin-setup/index.js:18:27)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1028:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/home/user/project/node_modules/node/installArchSpecificPackage.js'
  ]
}
npm WARN tsutils@3.17.1 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node@8.10.0 preinstall: `node installArchSpecificPackage`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node@8.10.0 preinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/user/.npm/_logs/2019-12-03T04_30_24_450Z-debug.log
```

Is there a better way to fix this without relying on the unsafe perm parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how to solve this error. Run this command:

```
sudo chown -R $USER /home/user/project/node_modules/
```

> Pay attention to the folder listed by the error message. If it’s
>   different, update the chown command accordingly.

Let’s break it down:

`sudo` means we are running this command as root, the system super user. This is because we don’t have permission to write to that folder, but root will be able to fix any permission. This command also means the system will ask for your password to confirm.

`chown` is the command we use to change the owner of a file or folder. We set the -R option to change the owner recursively, so we also get owner access to all the files already contained in there.

`$USER` is an environment variable automatically set to your username.

And the final piece is the folder path.

Running this path will make the folder yours, so you can safely run your `npm install -g <package>` commands!

Comment: Ah thanks, I managed to fix it by using the command sudo chown -R $USER:$username /home/username/.config

Comment: Hai @R.Gao If you satisfied with answer, you can upvote the answer by clicking the up arrow besides the answer. Thanks.